# How do I initiate a custom MKAnnotationView with a custom MKAnnotation?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I'm trying to associate a custom annotation view with a custom annotation. How do I do this?

here's where I setup the annotation view and associate it with the custom annotation:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        guard !annotation.isKind(of: MKUserLocation.self) else {
            // Make a fast exit if the annotation is the `MKUserLocation`, as it's not an annotation view we wish to customize.
            return nil
        }
        
        var annotationView: MKAnnotationView?
        
        if let annotation = annotation as? HangAnnotation {
            annotationView = setupHangAnnotationView(for: annotation, on: mapView)
        } 

        return annotationView
    }
    private func setupHangAnnotationView(for annotation: HangAnnotation, on mapView: MKMapView) -> MKAnnotationView {
        
        let hangAnnotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: K.identifiers.hangViewIdentifier, for: annotation) as? HangAnnotationView
            hangAnnotationView?.delegate = self
            hangAnnotationView?.canShowCallout = false
            return hangAnnotationView!
    }
```

(note: I know the custom annotation is successfully created because its data members can be accessed within setupHangAnnotationView() above)

Here's where I attempt to initialize the created AnnotationView with the custom annotation:

```
class HangAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {

     override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        hangButton = UIButton(frame: annotationFrame)
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

as you can see the required type is MKAnnotation for the override init, so how do I pass the custom annotation into my initializer? I'm super stuck so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It is there; the first argument `annotation` - Simply downcast it to `HangAnnotation`

Comment: @Paulw11 how would I do that? I tried force downcasting annotation in super.init() but get a fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional, and it doesn't appear to be an option in the override init, unless there's some syntax I'm missing

Comment: If your downcast fails then you aren’t supplying the right annotation type. What did the exception say?  What was the type of the annotation?  You can also set a breakpoint and use the debugger